# How to access next line in a file(.txt) in Python

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a file and I open it and then I check for few things. If the line starts with "E PARAM" and also has "OOPS1" in it somewhere then I want to check that the next line starts with " E PARAM". If not I will make a new file and copy it there till the time I dont hit another "E PARAM" line. Since Python doesnt have a next() option... what can help me here

```
import string
import os


A = "k_trap_cur"
B = open(A, 'r+')
lines = B.readline()

for lines in B:
    if lines.startswith("E PRAM"):
        if "OOPS: 1" in lines:
            while lines.next().startswith("E PARAM") == False: // HERE I want to access next line
                print " YES"
```

Comment: read file with `read()` and split with "E PARAM"

Comment: My file is a huge file with lots of lines. In the while loop I want to check if the next line starts with ("E PARAM") or not. I dont have to split it

Comment: use `next(B)` or `B.readline()` inside your loop to look at the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
b = open(a, 'r+')
for line in b:
    if line.startswith("E PRAM") and "OOPS: 1" in line:
        next_line = next(b)
        # do whatever you need
```

Files provide what is called an “Iterator protocol” and that's why they work in `for`-loops. You can also call `next` function on them manually, if you want. Check [PEP-234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) for more details.

Comment: @kirelagin.. Thanks soo much for the link. I tried doing what you said but it gives me an error. CODE: for lines in B:
        if lines.startswith("EchoStar PRAM") and "OOPS: 1" in lines:
                next_line = next(B)
                print next_line
Error:    next_line = next(B)
NameError: name 'next' is not defined

Comment: :- Error: next_line = next(B) NameError: name 'next' is not defined

Comment: @Nick [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) was added in Python 2.6, probably, your version is older. Then `next_line = next(b)` should work.